# vba and condition fails when condition satisfies

Tags: excel, vba

below is my code here , where box is value 5 say at 12 degree testing various conditions of book and assigning box values
conditions:-

1. book is at 10 degree then it should give result should be 5 and 4
2. book is at 14 degree then it should give result as 5 and 4
3. book is at 19 degree then result should be 5
4. book is at 5 degree then the result should be 4

but the and conditions fail for my code.

```
Function FindboxOccupy(chkbook As String) As String
Dim result
Dim booksign, boxno, upperbox, lowerbox
Dim bookradian As Variant, boxradian As Variant, upperorb As Variant, lowerorb As Variant


For Each b In Worksheets("mylist").Range("A2:A10")
If b.Value = chkbook Then
booksign = b.Offset(0, 5).Value
bookradian = b.Offset(0, 8).Value
    For Each c In Worksheets("mylist").Range("F14:F25")
    If c.Value = booksign Then
    
    boxradian = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
    boxnos = c.Offset(0, -5).Value
    upperbox = boxnos + 1
    lowerbox = boxnos - 1
    
    If lowerbox = 0 Then
    lowerbox = 12
    End If
    If upperbox > 12 Then
    upperbox = 1
    End If
        
        
        upperorb = bookradian + 4
        lowerorb = bookradian - 4
        
        If bookradian < boxradian Then
        result = lowerbox
        End If
        
        If bookradian >= boxradian Then
        result = boxnos
        End If
        
        If bookradian < boxradian And boxradian <= upperorb Then
        result = result & "," & boxnos
        End If
        
        If bookradian >= boxradian And boxradian > lowerorb Then
        result = result & "," & lowerbox
        End If
        
        
    End If
    Next c
End If
Next b

FindboxOccupy = result
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a single occurrence of `chkbook` in the iterated range? If so, you should use `Exit For` before the `End If` of `If c.Value = booksign Then` condition.  VBA conditions never fail... Your **conditioning algorithm** should be checked, I am afraid. If only one of the above 4 conditions **must be True**, I think you should use `ElseIf` and place all of them in a unique `If ... End If`. Then place a break point of the line `boxradian = c.Offset(0, 3).Value` and when code stops, run each line using `F8` and move the cursor over the involved variable and **see what's happening**...

Comment: You should put option explicit at the start of every module/class/formcode.  Then silly mistakes such as Boxno vs Boxnos will be detected.  You should also read up on the use of the else and elseif clauses of the If then end if structure, because if something is > than a value then everything else is <=.